AtomicStampedReference#compareAndSet performing checks sequentially using logical connectives
public boolean compareAndSet(V   expectedReference,
                             V   newReference,
                             int expectedStamp,
                             int newStamp) {
    Pair<V> current = pair;
    return
        expectedReference == current.reference &&
        expectedStamp == current.stamp &&
        ((newReference == current.reference &&
          newStamp == current.stamp) ||
         casPair(current, Pair.of(newReference, newStamp)));
}

This is the source code of compactAndSet method of AtomicStampedReference.
Why does it use newReference == current.reference && newStamp == current.stamp? Are the multiple boolean logical judgments here atomic? If not, after judging expectedReference == current.reference && expectedStamp == current.stamp, if other threads modify current.reference to newReference and current.stamp to newStamp, it will return true and not execute casPair(current, Pair.of(newReference, newStamp). But actually, this modification is completed by other threads, and why return true?

The important part here is the first statement:
Pair<V> current = pair;

When you look into the casPair method, you can see that it swaps the entire pair and the fields of Pair are final.
So, it doesn't compare the values after each other but instead first gets both values and then compares the values that are already obtained. So the newReference == current.reference && newStamp == current.stamp doesn't actually check the state of the of the receiver directly, this has been done before when retrieving the Pair.

But actually, this modification is completed by other threads, and why return true?

This is essentially the same thing. The value is atomically retrieved using Pair<V> current = pair; and then compared to it. This only happens if expectedReference, current.reference and newReference (as well as expectedStamp, current.stamp and newStamp) are the same with respect to the object retrieved by Pair<V> current = pair;.
In this case, you have the situation that you are setting the value to the new value if it already has that exact value. In that case, you have the same behavior without changing the value as setting a value to itself doesn't have any side effect. If someone else changes the AtomicStampedReference in the meantime, that change can be consider to have happened "later".

The comment of the method is very informative:
    /**
     * Atomically sets the value of both the reference and stamp
     * to the given update values if the
     * current reference is {@code ==} to the expected reference
     * and the current stamp is equal to the expected stamp.
     *
     * @param expectedReference the expected value of the reference
     * @param newReference the new value for the reference
     * @param expectedStamp the expected value of the stamp
     * @param newStamp the new value for the stamp
     * @return {@code true} if successful
     */

It checks whether:
- current reference matches the expected reference
- AND
- current stamp matches the expected stamp
- AND
        - current reference matches new reference
        - AND
        - current stamp matches new stamp
    - OR
        - succeeding with the update

So basically, it first checks whether stamp and reference matches the expected values. If so, it checks whether the new value is the same as the expected one, in which case there is no need to update. If that's false, then the update executes.
So the new reference and stamp comparison to the current one is the first operand of a logical OR expression, which, if happens to be true, the second operand, the actual update will not be evaluated.
So it translates to this in short:
If the current reference and stamp matches their expected counterpart, then we update the new stamp and reference as long as they differ from the current/expected counterpart.
